# Cordova chrome.socket API. Any example?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app

I am trying to use org.chromium.socket plugin. But I cannot find many examples. Here is my code:

```
var connButton = document.getElementById("connButton");

connButton.addEventListener("click", doConnect, false);

function doConnect() {
    var theSocketId = 0;
    chrome.socket.create("tcp", null, function(createInfo) {
        alert(createInfo.socketId);
        theSocketId = createInfo.socketId;
     });
     chrome.socket.connect(theSocketId, "http://www.yahoo.com", 80, function(result) {
        alert(result);
     });
chrome.socket.read(theSocketId, 1000, function(readInfo) {
      alert(readInfo.resultCode);
  });
  }
```

I try to change the host name to different IP or change the port. But sometime I see result = -1000, which indicates failure. Or sometime I cannot see result alert. I also have problem using chrome.socket.read.

Please critique my code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

The best API examples for this plugin are probably those published on GitHub at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/. They're for the chrome.socket API, which is what the plugin implements. In particular, you can check out the [TCP Server](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/tcpserver), [Web Server](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webserver) and [Websocket Server](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/websocket-server).

I also wrote a simple web server using the plugin as a demo back in September; you can find it [on GitHub here](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-app-samples/tree/master/webServer)

These examples all show server sockets, though -- I don't have a good example to show you of the client side.

As far as your code goes, two things stand out immediately:

First, you are attempting to connect to TCP port 0, which is almost certainly incorrect. TO connect to an HTTP service, you should leave out the "http://" from the address -- just use the server name, and use 80 as the port number.

Second, it looks like you are calling `chrome.socket.connect` immediately after `chrome.socket.create`, and `chrome.socket.read` immediately after `chrome.socket.connect`, rather than doing these in callbacks. This might mean that the connect call could be issued before the create is finished, or the read call could be issued before the bind call is completed. I would start by nesting the calls, like this:

```
chrome.socket.create("tcp", null, function(createInfo) {
    alert(createInfo.socketId);
    theSocketId = createInfo.socketId;
    chrome.socket.connect(theSocketId, "www.yahoo.com", 80, function(result) {
        alert(result);
        if (result === 0) {
            chrome.socket.read(theSocketId, 1000, function(readInfo) {
                alert(readInfo.resultCode);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

However, the next thing that's going to stop this from working is that the code doesn't actually send any request to the server. `chrome.socket` is a low-level interface, and so if you want to communicate over HTTP, your app is going to have to talk HTTP.

A very simple bit of example code that will talk to a web server, and return the first thousand bytes of its home page, looks like this:

```
// Utility functions to convert between array buffers and strings

function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (var i=0; i < string.length; i++) {
        bufView[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buffer;
}

function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
}

// Set the hostname; we'll need it for the HTTP request as well
var hostname = "www.yahoo.com";

chrome.socket.create("tcp", function(createInfo) {
    var socketId = createInfo.socketId;
    chrome.socket.connect(socketId, hostname, 80, function(result) {
        if (result === 0) {
            var requestString = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+hostname+"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
            var requestBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer(requestString);
            chrome.socket.write(socketId, requestBuffer, function(writeInfo) {
                chrome.socket.read(socketId, 1000, function(readInfo) {
                    var htmlString = arrayBufferToString(readInfo.data);
                    // do something with htmlString here
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to find some client codes, rather than server code, that utilize the API.

Comment: Really thanks for your comment. As to the port, I previously have tried 80 before. But they all return nth as result. But if I use null,   it returns -1000 as result. And the last time I try, which use 0 as port as shown, which I know is obviously incorrect, also return nth.

Comment: I have changed the port number from 0 to 80. 0 is obviously incorrect. I just try to set it to 0 to see if anything happens.

Comment: After the port, and nesting the function calls in callbacks, I added the last step above: Sending the HTTP request before trying to read data.

Comment: TCP and Webserver links are down :D

Comment: Looks like they reorganized the GitHub repo, thanks for the tip! I've updated the links now.