# Getting chrome.socket plugin example to run under Cordova

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to the example from this question to working on an Android tablet.

[Cordova chrome.socket API. Any example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549111/cordova-chrome-socket-api-any-example)

The example is failing and I believe its because the network permissions that go in the manifest.json file are not set.

My question is where does this belong or where do I place these permissions.

Thanks for the help.

Jack

Comment: Are you trying this in a bare Cordova application? Or are you trying to build a Cordova-based CCA app?

Comment: This is a Cordova solution

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any special manifest permissions for a Cordova app. As long as you're using the example code in the answer (not the question ;) )

The only caveat that I'm aware of with Cordova apps is that you need to explicitly wait for the  "`deviceready`" event before the `chrome.socket` API is available.

I've just tested with this JS, and my device (Nexus 7) connects to Yahoo and downloads the first thousand bytes of the home page, logging it to the console.

```
function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (var i=0; i < string.length; i++) {
        bufView[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buffer;
}

function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
}

// Set the hostname; we'll need it for the HTTP request as well
var hostname = "www.yahoo.com";

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    chrome.socket.create("tcp", function(createInfo) {
        var socketId = createInfo.socketId;
        chrome.socket.connect(socketId, hostname, 80, function(result) {
            if (result === 0) {
                var requestString = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+hostname+"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
                var requestBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer(requestString);
                chrome.socket.write(socketId, requestBuffer, function(writeInfo) {
                    chrome.socket.read(socketId, 1000, function(readInfo) {
                        var htmlString = arrayBufferToString(readInfo.data);
                        // do something with htmlString here
                        console.log(htmlString);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: This is an ionic app running on a Samsung Tab 3.  It Android version 4.1.2.  Is that my problem?  I started with an unmodifed ionic todo app and added "chrome.sockets" plugin.  I always get a return value from the connect of -1000.  It is after the device ready event has been called.

Comment: This turns out to be caused by an "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". I tried it on the $ionicPlatform.ready event and it still raises this exception.  Any ideas why it work on your device (other than it likely not an iconic application)

Comment: It could be a 4.1 difference -- I'm pretty sure that we've tested sockets back as far as 4.0.4, but I'll see if I can try it on 4.1.2. Can you add a traceback to your question, so I can see where the exception is happening>

Comment: In the end I wrapped the guts of the execute function in ChromeSocket.java in cordova.getThreadPool().execute(...) and it worked.

Comment: That would be the way to do it; I was just hoping to get an error report to see which methods were causing problems. Thanks.