# Can you connect to a LAN IP from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, browser, ping, lan

A program I'm developing connects directly over the LAN between 2 computers. Sometimes, a user will have 2 computers on different networks, so the computers won't be able to connect to each other (or ping each other). I want to give the user the possibility of testing this LAN-to-LAN connectivity before downloading and installing the main program.

Is it possible to or connect to (or ping) one computer from another over LAN using Chrome or any other browser? This would also involve detecting the local IP address.

My hunch is that Chrome (and other browsers) won't provide this sort of access to the OS (i.e. with JavaScript or an extension), but maybe there's an alternative (dare I say, a Java Applet, if that's still a thing). A bonus would be if this could work on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ping is an application, just like Chrome is an application.

Comment: Indeed, this is an example. Maybe it's possible to create a socket for another computer to listen to? What about querying the IP address or hostname? Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be Chrome?  Can you just create a process to ping the other computer?

Comment: The user downloads the app from a web browser, so it'd be more seamless if they didn't have to install a program or run a process manually. It'd be great if I could run a Chrome extension that creates a TCP socket or something...

Comment: @RonMaupin Maybe Chrome Sockets? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp

Answer (score 1):

Found this question:

[Can You Get A Users Local LAN IP Address Via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript)

Which has an answer linking to:

[net.ipcalf.com](http://net.ipcalf.com/)

If you hit F12 you can look at the source code and attempt to reverse engineer it, but I recommend researching it independently as well.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about this. Feels a bit cumbersome. It needs to be automatic, rather than making the user think.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, take another look

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to or connect to (or ping) one computer from another over LAN using Chrome or any other browser?

[Chrome Sockets](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp), perhaps. Though I have no idea how.

Comment: Can someone expand on this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22549111/cordova-chrome-socket-api-any-example

Comment: Oh! Multicast... https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/multicast

Answer (score 0):

> This would also involve detecting the local IP address.

This Chrome extension shows your local IPs: [Show My IP Addresses (External and Local)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-my-ip-addresses-exte/opljiobgnagdjikipnagigiacllolpaj?hl=en)

I wonder how this works...